# How to use ember-2-legacy?

Tags: ember.js, legacy

We have the post in the documentation for Ember 2.16 about addition deprecation `ember-2-legacy`:

> Ember 2 Legacy
> until: 3.4
> id: ember-2-legacy
> Ember provides ember-2-legacy which is an addon to help app with deprecations during the transition from the 2.x series to 3.x.

https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v2.x/#toc_ember-2-legacy

We also have some configuration in README:

> In ember-cli-build.js you can specify a config for ember-2-legacy

https://github.com/emberjs/ember-2-legacy#what-deprecations-are-covered

So, as I understand, if we specify some flag with `false`, like this:

```
new EmberApp(defaults, {
  'ember-2-legacy': {
    'enumerable-contains': false
```

then this particular feature will be off in ember app.

Should my App raise some error or notify me by console warning?
In general, I have a case of all flags `false` and all tests passed, so my question is: is it mean that my application has no those deprecations usage cases?

Shall I keep `ember-2-legacy` with config in `ember-cli-build.js` til Ember upgrade 3.0

or

case with no errors on CI build means that: my App already has no deprecation and I can remove this addon at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ember-2-legacy` should be installed *after* you upgrade to `3.0`.

If you have no deprecations on `2.18` you dont need it. But if you for example use `Ember.K` which is deprecated on  `2.18` you can upgrade to `3.0` and use `ember-2-legacy` with `'ember-k': true` without having to remove the `Ember.K` code.

Which gives you time until ember `3.4` to remove the use of `Ember.K`.

So installing `ember-2-legacy` on ember `2.x` should not do anything.